# Ubuntu 14.04 boot up, login, but once in desktop I can't do anything

Tags: 14.04, latex, texlive

I can boot Ubuntu 14.04 and login into my user session. Once I do that, I get to the normal desktop page. I can move my mouse and if I hold Super the shortcuts appear.

The problem is that it's the only things I can do: no button will react, be it the setting button, any desktop app or the apps in the left scrolling panel. The left panel will not scroll down or do anything either. I've tried to use hotkeys but nothing works.

The last program I installed is Cirkuit, which might have caused the problem, the code I used is:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pstricks texlive-base-bin texlive-extra-utils preview-latex-style m4 ghostscript pdf2svg
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install cmake kdelibs5-dev libqt4-dev libpoppler-qt4-dev
```

Which, looking at the age of the post I used http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Cirkuit?content=107098 might not have been a good idea.

Comment: If you're using the your Linux installation on a virtual machine, try to disable 3d acceleration. I had similar symptoms on my virtual  Linux before and solved it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I booted up in recovery mode (root terminal) and removed the packages I'd installed:

```
apt remove cmake kdelibs5-dev libqt4-dev libpoppler-qt4-dev
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid answer but it sounds like there might be something wrong with your mouse. Have you tested it on a different OS? Do other keyboard commands work e.g. does Crtl+Alt+T open a terminal?